# Does installing a wamp stack on server change anything that could break other server software?

Tags: xampp, wamp, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to install a Wamp stack on our company server, either wamp or xampp. This server is using windows server 2012 R2 Standard and runs a VB.net application, and other software that I might not be aware of.

I am almost sure that xampp or wamp edits the hosts file in windows directory, and I am not sure if there is other files also edited or created for it to run.

I want to know if it is safe to install a Wamp stack, and if something breaks, would a uninstall of the lamp stack revert all changes to its original state?

Comment: LAMP would mean linux. And well, without knowing what else you run installing a web server would be risky. Good idea to talk to someone who knows what he's doing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I saw that lamp meant linux, unfortunately i have no idea what group name I would use for windows stack.

Comment: More that, based off the question, you probably should ask someone else what that server is used for, and what software is on *before* you do anything.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the bigger picture is that I want to create prototype of the vb.net app in php. And without having a working prototype, my proposal to switch to different programming language would not even be looked at. So I would like to do this under the radar.

Comment: Build it on a VM then. Don't mix production and production.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You could add that as an answer, it could definitely solve the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

***Don't***

> "This server is using windows server 2012 R2 Standard and runs a
>   VB.net application, and other software that I might not be aware of."

So.. you don't know what's running where.

> I am almost sure that xampp or wamp edits the hosts file in windows
>   directory, and I am not sure if there is other files also edited or
>   created for it to run.

I suspect its self contained, but once again, not really enough to information to tell.

> I want to know if it is safe to install a Lamp stack, and if something
>   breaks, would a uninstall of the lamp stack revert all changes to its
>   original state?

From what you've said? Likely not.

> the bigger picture is that I want to create prototype of the vb.net
>   app in php. And without having a working prototype, my proposal to
>   switch to different programming language would not even be looked at.
>   So I would like to do this under the radar.

Awesome. Let me save your job. *Don't*

Get a VM host installed on hardware *you* control, and won't take down what seems to be an important company resource, and develop your prototype. Do not mix development and production.